# Filestream with Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, filestream

Ok now, the current code i am using

```
{
    using (fs = new FileStream("test", FileMode.Create))
    {

        byte[] b = new byte[iLength + 1];
        int y1 = 0;
        axCZKEM1.GetPhotoByName(MachineNo, photoPath + ".jpg", out b[0], out y1);


        btImage = b;


        if (btImage != null)
        {

            fs.Write(btImage, 0, btImage.Length);
        }


        if (fs.Length > 0)
        {


            bmp1 = new Bitmap(fs);

            bmp1.Save(ImgPath + photoPath + ".jpg");
            Console.WriteLine(photoPath);
            // fs = null;
            bmp1 = new Bitmap(fs);
```

When i use the above code in backgroundworker or in thread (   bmp1 = new Bitmap(fs); ) this line is throwing Parameter is not valid exception , if somebody can help me out on this please.

Comment: `bmp1 = new Bitmap(fs)` which one, there are 2

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway, Save the image to a the `FileStream`?

Comment: the First One 

bmp1 = new Bitmap(fs);


also , trying to save Image from a filestream fetched through zktecho machine

if i am not using thread then i am not facing any issues